# Caveats passing argument as constant reference in multi-thread application

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any disadvantage passing as const and by reference in multithread application?

I did some research but could not find any answer which explains its behavior with threading and it caveats.

Comment: I think to answer this probably requires an entire book or course, not one answer! But basically, if you have references to the same object in different threads, you need some sort of synchronisation. If **all** the references are to `const`, then you **may** be safe (assuming the class is well designed).

Comment: About const thread-safety: [Const means Thread-safe?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274548/const-means-thread-safe)

Comment: Actually passing by value is probably worse,

Comment: And [C++11 Multithreading - Carefully Pass Arguments to Threads](https://thispointer.com/c11-multithreading-part-3-carefully-pass-arguments-to-threads/)

Comment: Is it safe to assume if we use primitive data types and pass by const ref, is it thread safe?

Comment: @BoBTFish You don't need synchronisation if all the accesses are reads. Or if it is guaranteed that only one write and no reads happen. How to achieve these guarantees is what could fill books.

Comment: @SumitJha The underlying rule is simple: If multiple threads access the same object and **at least one of those accesses is a write** then you have a problem, otherwise you are fine. And then you also have to worry about lifetimes (but that is yet another wide field in C++).

Comment: Isn't is that even the function pass as const ref but creates a copy of the object it in thread's stack? making it thread-safe?

Comment: There is also a talk about thread-safety [here](https://youtu.be/s5PCh_FaMfM). Since C++ has `mutable` as well as `const_cast` it is not easy to say what is thread-save and what is not (without looking at the code)

Comment: "pass as const ref but creates a copy of the object it in thread's stack" nope, that doesn't create a copy. You can create a copy by passing by value, however then you have to ensure that copy is created thread-safe (which is actually not easy to achieve if passing by value and something can write to the original value).

Comment: http://cpp.sh/73gw6 @axalis if look at example, how do you explain the behavior?

Comment: Oh yeah, in that case actually the copy is done by the std:::thread itself (calling to `std::decay_copy` eventually). You would need `std::thread threadObj(threadCallback, std::ref(x));` to really pass by reference. So in that case if all threads have a copy it would be probably safe (however note that the value will not be shared, ie. each thread will work with its own copy and will not see any potential updates to the original one).

Comment: @axalis that means as far the classes are designed properly (rule of 3 or 5) with deep copy and i just want to read, it should be fine. Of course it would not be in sync with the object originally passed until I pass as `std::ref`.